# How to access Data.json using dalle api key

Tags: json

help me to find a solution of the given erro... SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'B', "Billing ha"... is not valid JSON.

I am using Dalle_api_key of image generation but while parsing the json data it is showing this error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make a new account at open ai and use the api key from the new account. You are facing this error because the api is paid. With the new account you will get 5$ worth of free credits, each api call costs 0.02$ so be careful making too much requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by creating a new account at Open AI then creating a new API key and using it in your project.

[Error Img][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOtpQ.png

Comment: What is this answer providing that was not provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/76145215/12846804 posted 5 months before yours? (Also is image essential?)